# Modify text attribute of UILabels in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, uilabel

I have an `NSMutableArray` full of `UILabels` and I want to modify the text attribute of them by stepping through the `array`. I know its not a problem with the `UILabels` or the function generating the text I want assigned to the labels as I have tested it outside of the array and it works fine. I just cant seem to get the text attribute to modify while the `UILabel` is inside of an array.

I have the array populated as below:

```
NSMutableArray *scrambledWordLabelArray;

-(void)initUIArrays {
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel1 atIndex:0];
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel2 atIndex:1];
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel3 atIndex:2];
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel4 atIndex:3];
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel5 atIndex:4];
    [scrambledWordLabelArray insertObject:ScrambledWordLabel6 atIndex:5];
}
```

Then once the view loads its supposed to change the labels to the strings generated by the other function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    [self initUIArrays];

    currentGameList = [self GetWordList:[self LoadWordlist]];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [currentGameList count]; i++) {
```

For this part I found two solutions, neither worked for me...

Solution 1:

```
         UILabel *temp = [scrambledWordLabelArray objectAtIndex:i];
         temp.text = [self ScrambleWord:[currentGameList objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Solution 2:

```
         [[scrambledWordLabelArray objectAtIndex:i] setText:[self ScrambleWord:[currentGameList objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I've been researching and debugging for hours with no fix :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize the scrambledWordLabelArray. You need to add the following line:

```
scramledWordLabelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

On a side note:

Is it true that currentGameList and scrambledWordLabelArray will always have the same number of elements? Your 'for' loop is based on the number of elements in the currentGameList yet you use the same index to get elements from the scrambledWordLabelArray.

Both solutions you posted are basically the same code.

Comment: I was about to write that myself... (in case the OP doesn't initialize the `NSMutableArray` at some other place, that is...)

Comment: Bah! Thats it! Originally I had it that where I first declared the array but it told me it wasn't a compile time constant and when I took the count of the array it returned 6 so I assumed that the object were in there. Thank you very much!